# Is it proper form to change a Django model in a RedirectView?

Tags: django

I am doing something that seems unorthodox but I'm not sure the best practice. I'm allowing people to unsubscribe to emails through a link. They can either click the link from an email, or click the link from their settings page.

I'm implementing a Django `RedirectView` like this:

```
class UnsubscribeView(RedirectView):                                                
    permanent=False                                                                 

    def get_redirect_url(self, *args, **kwargs):                                    
        member = Member.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)                        
        member.email_me = False                                       
        member.save()                                                               
        return reverse('profile_page', args=[member.pk])
```

It basically reloads the page with the opposite value for that setting when they unsubscribe from the settings page. From an email, it also unsubscribes them and brings them to their settings page.

Are there drawbacks to using this type of construction for changing user settings through a redirect?

Thanks!

Comment: the only thing that appears as unorthodox is that you use a GET to change your  instance attributes, but as your link may appear in mail, there are no real alternative (as far as you cannot POST data from email, which is good :p). What part did you think was unorthodox ? the redirection ?

Comment: @RaphaëlBraud yes, the GET and the fact that I'll have a 302 in my site. Because what I'm trying to accomplish requires a GET, do you think modifying the profile_page GET makes more sense?

Comment: Having a 302 is not unorthodox in this context : in Django documentation, you often see code with side effects (attribute modification + save) followed by a redirection. No, I don't think modifying profile_page GET makes more sense : as it is, UnsuscribeView and profile_page will have cleanly separated responsability. Moreover, in the specific mail context, what happens on the HTTP level is more logical that what it would be if you'd modify profile_page : you click on a unsuscribe link, then, you're redirected to the profile page